# Why does my installed application fail to run?

Tags: .net, installation, release

I've got a .NET 3.5 Application that was working well. The installation was also working and the application functioned properly after installation.

I've fixed a few bugs and rebuilt the setup but now I can't get the installed application to run. I'm completely removing the old install, re-installing and when I run it I get the:

```
Data Tool has stopped working...
Windows is checking for a solution to the problem...
```

- I don't even get a .net exception...
- Running from the release folder works.
- If I copy the files from the release folder into (and overwrite) 'Program Files' it runs

Any ideas?

**Update:**
I'm using a VS2008 deployment project to build my installer...

Comment: Sounds like a missing dll reference, or some registry configuration you forgot to update.

Comment: So do a diff between the version in the release folder and the version in Program Files - see which files are wrong.

Comment: @Jon I did think about doing that, but if I found any differences I wouldn't know where to look then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted and re-added the 'Primary Output' in the setup project and it appears to have fixed it.
I've been trying to work this out all morning!